# How to Re-order Background Pages in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I have created a Microsoft Visio (specifically, Professional 2013) document with  four background pages.

I'd like to re-order the background pages, but it seems Microsoft Visio does not allow me to do so.

What I've tried:

1. Click and drag: Microsoft Visio shows a circle-slash icon when I hover over another page
2. "Reorder pages..." popup (via right-click on background page tab): Microsoft Visio displays only foreground pages in the list, not background pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of Background pages cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks! As a Visio power user, do you have any understanding of why Microsoft has never implemented this, by chance (?)

Comment: No idea at all, but it had also never been implemented by the company that wrote Visio in the first place, so I assume there is some basic reason why it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but a work around: duplicate the background pages IN THE ORDER YOU WANT. Then reassign the foreground pages to the new background pages. Delete the old backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

A short cut that I just tried is to right click on the tab >> page set up under Page Properties, change back to Foreground, no background.  Do this for the pages you want to move.  Move them, then apply the background again. Much easier :).